# PHP special pattern

Tags: php, html, regex

I am using `preg_match_all()` in order to extract all the key string from an HTML file.
Every single key string is inside a pattern like `_@#$%&KEY_NAME&%$#@_`.

So I have:

```
$html = file_get_contents("htmlFile.html");
if ($html){
  $matches = null;
  $keys = preg_match_all("/(_@#\$%&)(?P<key>\w+)(&%\$#@_)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  if (($keys >= 0)&&($keys != false)){
     if ($keys == 0)
       echo "preg_match_all() returns 0";
     else{
        foreach($matches as $val)
           echo $val[key];
     }
  }
}
```

HTML file content:

```
<label for="button_ok">_@#$%&LABEL_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_</label>
<input type="button" value="_@#$%&TEXT_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_" />
```

When testing it at http://tryphpregex.com/ it saids that not pattern is found.

Answer (score 0):

Use double backslashes `\\` to quote the `$`

```
$html = '<label for="button_ok">_@#$%&LABEL_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_</label>
<input type="button" value="_@#$%&TEXT_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_" />';
preg_match_all("/(_@#\\$%&)(?P<key>\w+)(&%\\$#@_)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `('')` single quote to match string

```
$html = '<label for="button_ok">_@#$%&LABEL_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_</label>
<input type="button" value="_@#$%&TEXT_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_" />';
preg_match_all('/(_@#\$%&)(?P<key>\w+)(&%\$#@_)/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//print_r($matches);
echo $matches[0][0]; //_@#$%&LABEL_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_
echo $matches[1][0]; //_@#$%&TEXT_BUTTON_OK&%$#@_
```